# Oracle XA permission

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, sql-grant, xa

One of my application deployed on IBM WebSphere uses Oracle 12c database. This application does require XA transactions to be enabled on oracle and the user (connecting to oracle through datasource of websphere) should have XA permissions granted. How do I find if the user has been granted XA permissions? I tried running below queries to find the permission but no luck.

```
select * from dba_profiles where resource_name='IDLE_TIME';

select * from dba_profiles where resource_name='CONNECT_TIME';

select * from dba_2pc_pending;

select * from session_privs;

SELECT * FROM DBA_TAB_PRIVS;

SELECT * FROM DBA_TAB_PRIVS where owner='<schema_user>';

SELECT * FROM USER_ROLE_PRIVS;
```

I got to know that in Oracle 12, XA is enabled by default. But do we need to grant any permission to a schema owner to participate in the transactions?

Answer (score 2):

After several email exchanges with my DBA team, finally they granted permission on the user by executing below commands and it solved the problem. Hope this helps.

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON SYS.DBMS_XA TO <user>;
Prompt Privs on TABLE SYS.PENDING_TRANS$ to <user>;
GRANT SELECT ON SYS.PENDING_TRANS$ TO <user>;
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but you might need more than the 2 GRANTs that you applied depending on your in-house solution or external library requirements. In summary:

```sql
grant execute on dbms_xa                  to <user>;
grant select  on pending_trans$           to <user>; 
grant select  on dba_2pc_pending          to <user>;
grant select  on dba_pending_transactions to <user>;
```

Last of all, to find out if you have the correct permissions, simply try to access (SELECT/EXECUTE) in the tables/packages you need grants for. For example:

```sql
-- Running those in your <user> should not error.
SELECT * FROM sys.dba_pending_transactions;
SELECT * FROM sys.pending_trans$;
SELECT * FROM sys.dba_2pc_pending;
```

Or if you have access to `SYSDBA`:

```sql
select * from USER_TAB_PRIVS where Grantee = <user>;
```

---

As per the [Oracle XA Distributed Transactions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/clustering/overview/distributed-transactions-and-xa-163941.pdf) white paper:

Page 11,

> Similarly, for PL/SQL (from Oracle Database 11gR1), the XA_SETTIMEOUT function within the DBMS_XA package can be used to set the transaction timeout, the default value is 60 seconds.

Page 12,

> If a transaction times out and becomes “in-doubt”, it will appear in the DBA_2PC_PENDING and DBA_PENDING_TRANSACTIONS views.

Page 14,

> The Oracle database allows access to the following information on distributed transactions within the database:
>
> - Information on unresolved distributed transactions (e.g. prepared and awaiting commit/rollback) is available via the DBA_PENDING_TRANSACTIONS system view.
> - Information on distributed transactions awaiting recovery (e.g. “in-doubt” transactions) is available via the DBA_2PC_PENDING system view.
> - Information on the currently active distributed transactions is available via the V$GLOBAL_TRANSACTION system view.

Page 19:

> Any database account performing distributed transactions must have the following privileges:
>
> - Have permissions (GRANT) to read the DBA_PENDING_TRANSACTIONS system view.
> - Have permissions (GRANT) to the “FORCE ANY TRANSACTION” privilege, for database users who need to manipulate distributed transactions created by other database users.
>
> Additionally, when using RAC, user accounts must have the following privileges:
>
> - Have permissions (GRANT) to execute the DBMS_SYSTEM system package (for 9.2.0.8 or 10.2.0.3 and below, unless patches for 5945463
> - Server, 5965349 – OCI /C Library, 5892995 JDBC have been applied) or the DBMS_XA system package (10.2.0.4 or higher for database server, client OCI libraries or JDBC drivers).
> - Use Client and Server versions of the same patchset or with the appropriate patches applied to avoid mixing the use of the DBMS_SYSTEM package and DBMS_XA package within the same deployment.

Page 20,

> The functionality available in the XA interface to support transactions involving multiple resource managers, such as databases and queues. PL/SQL is now able to switch or share transactions across SQL*Plus sessions or processes using the XA/Open interface library contained within the DBMS_XA package (e.g. XA_START to join a transaction, XA_END to leave a transaction).

Page 24,

> Although the paper describes configuring an XA database user with permissions (GRANT) to execute
> the DBMS_SYSTEM system package for 10.2.0.3, this may require permissions on the DBMS_XA
> system package for later versions of the database.

Therefore, we need a SELECT GRANT to `DBA_2PC_PENDING` and `DBA_PENDING_TRANSACTIONS`. If we want to handle "in-doubt" transactions, something that Atomikos needs for many features (i.e. un/lock held by in-doubt distributed transaction, [Expired In-Doubt Transactions](https://www.atomikos.com/Documentation/HowToHandleExpiredInDoubtTransactions), ...etc.)

On top of that, we need the SELECT GRANT on `DBA_PENDING_TRANSACTIONS`. In regards to the `DBMS_SYSTEM`, we are using Oracle 11g (above 10.2.0.4) so we should EXECUTE GRANT to the `DBMS_XA` table.

If we want to understand why we are using DBMS_XA instead of DBMS_SYSTEM, see page 18, in which it explains the reason:

> Previously XA clients required execute privileges on DBMS_SYSTEM to invoke DIST_TXN_SYNC. This security enhancement required a change to both the server and client software (e.g. client OCI libraries and JDBC), such that the package DBMS_XA was called instead of DBMS_SYSTEM. This meant that to avoid user permission errors on database failover, all XA Client users now required execute privileges on DBMS_XA rather than DBMS_SYSTEM.

And in regards to the `pending_trans$`, XA tools like [Atomikos](https://www.atomikos.com/Documentation/ConfiguringOracleForXA#Oracle_10.2.0.4_44_11g_and_higher) team (and [IBM team](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/baw/19.x?topic=privileges-oracle-database)) might be using this value and therefore it is usually documented as a required grant.

Perhaps they derived this value through a [legacy documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19830-01/819-4712/ablst/index.html) that states:

> For Oracle, the database user for an XA datasource requires necessary permissions to be able to recover any transactions after Application Server has crashed and has been restarted. The Oracle permissions required on various tables for transaction recovery are:
>
> - SELECT permissions on DBA_PENDING_TRANSACTIONS, **PENDING_TRANS$**, DBA_2PC_PENDING and DBA_2PC_NEIGHBORS tables
> - EXECUTE permissions on DBMS_SYSTEM table

And, if you look at the [ORA-01500 to ORA-02098 range of errors](http://39.96.206.203/server.112/e17766/e1500.htm), you will see `PENDING_TRANS$` is being used/described.